# Не могу зайти в Настройки BIOS

Tags: железо, bios, asus

Материнская плата asus rog crosshair 7 hero.
Установлено 3 Карты rx 580 звуковая карта и 4 ОЗУ по 16Г. При загрузке выводится Лого и надпись нажмите del или F2 для входа в настройки, но не заходит в настройки при нажатии! ctrl alt del перезагружает машину, клавиатура usb. Что делать? помогите!

Comment: Попробуйте так: выключите из розетки и подождите не менее 1 минуты. Потом нажмите и удерживайте F2 клавишу , затем нажмите кнопку включения. НЕ отпускайте F2 клавишу,  пока не появится экран BIOS.

2. Проверить бы клавиатуру и еще порядок нажатия:
"... В любом случае, попытки войти в BIOS следует предпринимать после того, как мигнут или загорятся индикаторы на клавиатуре, но еще до начала загрузки операционной системы. "

Comment: И проверьте инс. к плате - вдруг там другая комбинация входа. Если что - сбросить настройки биос - выньте батарейку биоса при отключенном от сети на минуту минимум - и  вставьте обратно. И нажимать правильно) - то есть - после биканя и начала включения - пару раз нажать delete( и с f2 попробовать также)

Comment: Смените клавиатуру.

Comment: Батарейку вытаскивал, а операционной системы нет железо только собрал, есть другая клавиатура но тоже usb

Comment: @Coder f2 сработал после того как поменял клавиатуру , но он дал чёрный экран и завис , теперь при перезагрузке чёрный экран и черта в верхнем правом углу

Comment: @Gybernaty - значит, смотрите сборку - бывает, что с памятью проблемы - у меня на двух собранных с интервалом в месяц компах с разными материнками пришлось, по наитию обменять между ними память - хоть и по инструкции подходили к обоим, по факту работали только при замене оба компа.
Нук, и все сотальное нужно смотреть - позможно, переключатели на материнке, проц и прочая. Бывет еще перетяжка материнки и микротрещины - это не для ужастиков, но бывает. Еще и от статики при сборке летят элементы.. Что тут скажешь на пальцах? Оставьте минимум всего и пробуйте (1 карту, одну ОЗУ) - и меняйте их